why try_attach every list entry in __register_sysctl_paths of sysctl.c#kernel code
i am reading the sysctl code about linux kernel 3.3.8
in function __register_sysctl_paths of sysctl.c
why call try_attach on every entry of the list,
what is the meaning of 'improvement' on "/* see if attaching q to p would be an improvement */
static void try_attach(struct ctl_table_header *p, struct ctl_table_header *q)"?
    for (set = header->set; set; set = set->parent) {
        struct ctl_table_header *p;
        list_for_each_entry(p, &set->list, ctl_entry) {
            if (p->unregistering)
                continue;
            try_attach(p, header);
        }
    }

i am confused by these statements.

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   I see nothing in your question on-topic in your question, it's not a kernel used by any supported Ubuntu system, let alone you're asking a programming question
